# Where can I get a list of all Stocks that were acquired or went bankrupt

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, stock-exchanges, historical-data

I'm looking for a list of stocks from 2005 - present that were delisted from Nasdaq/NYSE due to being acquired/going bankrupt/going private/etc. Where can I get such data online (free or paid)?

Comment: You can find it on the exchange website where the stock was trading.

Answer (score 2):

[Where can I download all stock symbols of all companies "currently listed" and "delisted" as of today?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/36560/where-can-i-download-all-stock-symbols-of-all-companies-currently-listed-and)

That's incredibly similar . You can also do it with a Bloomberg terminal but there's no need to pay to do this because he data changes so slowly.

Comment: Actually, the data changes relatively quickly -- on a daily basis, in fact.  It's just that 99% of the companies being listed/delisted each day are ones that nobody's ever heard of.  Or it's one particular type of share that's being listed/delisted, rather than an entire company.

Comment: Oh good point @dg99 I was thinking of someone trying to see the history of the mega caps like the aigs the sun microsystems etc

Comment: The answer from the link you gave has a great resource to find a current list of all stocks but it doesn't have any info on where to find information on previously delisted stocks.